# Apply precedence in Algolia tagFilters

Tags: algolia

Is there a way to apply precedence in tagFilters query?

exp: `(Book AND Movie) OR SciFi`

[REF: tagFilters API parameter | Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/tagFilters/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend swapping from tagFilters to filters if you need more complex logic.

https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/filters/

Comment: If you mention your product or website in your answers you must disclose your affiliation. See: [How not to be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)